# How to find and replace an element in a list with Python

Tags: python

I have a `list` of `tuples` with some data like this: `[('word1','sentence1'),('word2','sentence1'),('word3','sentence1') ...]`, I loop on every tuple to get each word and sentence like this:

```
for collection in tup:
        qword = collection[0]
        sentence = collection[1]
```

so far, so good. I needed to remove each word from the sentence so I did this:

```
q_sentence_split = sentence.split()
new_sentence_split = [word.replace(q_word, '.....') for word in q_sentence_split]
new_sentence = ' '.join(sentence_split)
```

but This didn't give me what I needed, as it removes the characters of the `word` of the tuple from each word in the `q_senetnce_split`, but what I need is the word only, not comparing the characters of the word to the characters of each word of the sentence.

I tried putting if after the `for word in q_sentence_split` like this:

```
new_sentence_split = [word.replace(q_word, '.....') for word in q_sentence_split if word == qword]
```

but this just removed every word the sentence, so I don't know what is wrong with my code

Comment: `[re.sub(r"\b" + w + r"\b", "", s) for w, s in list_of_tuples]` Docs: [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). Pattern: [`\bword\b`](https://regex101.com/r/N4CNrN/2)

Comment: you didn't get me, I am trying to remove a word from the sentence, like this:
`the word --> asd    the sentence sss 'asd''asd' lh'asd'g kgkgk
what I want is to remove only 'asd' , what is actual is that it removes 'asd' and 'asdasd'`

Comment: Have you tried code from previous comment?

Comment: can you clarify your suggestion

Comment: Literally, you can just [run the code](https://tio.run/##HYsxDgIhEEV7TvFDMxCJjY2NJ9EtGMVIsgIZMBtPj7MWL3l5@b99x6uW07nJnPndqgxIMmbFBVdHkQIognFHjOQDHPGemLUlPMgvRlLfx5KO/cNO7I0tDtiUvwdYpXs8q2BTQy5YF9Mkl@H07Of8AQ) and see what happens.

Comment: ok, thx, can you post ur answer

Comment: I have 1 more question, does it work with all languages, cause I am trying with arabic and it just gave me the word to remove + sentence in a list

Comment: It will work with any language, it's just regular expression. Second argument of `re.sub()` is replacement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
lst = [('word1', 'The word1 is in this sentence'), ('word2', 'The word2blawblaw is in this sentence'),
       ('word3', 'The word1 is in this sentence')]

for word, sentence in lst:
    print(' '.join(i for i in sentence.split() if word not in i))
```

output :

```
The is in this sentence
The is in this sentence
The word1 is in this sentence
```

I intentionally put `word1` in third sentence.

**Explanation :**

First we iterate through `lst`, it gives us a tuple in each iteration, we unpack it with `word, sentence`.

After splitting the `sentence` it becomes a list which is `['The', 'word1', 'is', 'in', 'this', 'sentence']` (in first iteration).

Then again we iterate through this list which gives us the individual words, all we have to do is to chech if our `word` is inside any of these words or not. If it wasn't there that's what we want.

finally we do `' '.join()` to make the sentence.

Comment: can you explain ur answer

Comment: ok, ur answer works, but I need to understand it as I need to replace the word with sth else

Comment: @Div_OR, run separately next code snippets: `"The word1 is in this sentence".split()`, `"word1" in ["word1", "word2"]`, `" ".join(["The", "word1", "sentence"])`

Comment: I don't understand, how this is gonna help

Comment: @Div_OR it should help you to understand how does code from question works.

Comment: I don't understand the `"word1" in ["word1", "word2"]`

Comment: ok, how can I replace the word with ...... for example and then `join`

Comment: `print(' '.join(i if i != word else "replacement" for i in sentence.split()))`

Comment: @Div_OR I've updated the answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
list1 = [('word1', 'The word1 is in this sentence'), ('word2', 'The word2blawblaw is in this sentence'),
       ('word3', 'The word1 is in this sentence')]

for x, y in list1:
    print(' '.join(i for i in y.split() if word not in i))
```

Comment: thx for the effort but I already got my answer